# How to create app bundle file in uno platform?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle, uno

I am new to the uno platform.

I would like to build an Android app using the uno platform and publish it to the Google Play Console.

However, as you know, Google Play Console can only publish app bundle files, not apk files.

When building with the uno platform, only the apk file is created and the app bundle file is not created. How can I generate the app bundle file?

[image]

Thank you for reading and I appreciate any help you may have.